# My D-Link WiFi has an annoying issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Today, I turned my D-link 2750u router on and I have a problem with the WiFi connection.

The WiFi LED light on my router turns on and off every 5 seconds (i.e, I connect to WiFi and disconnect from it every 5 seconds!).

I can connect to the internet via Ethernet cable (i.e LAN interface), but I cannot connect to the internet with WiFi.

Furthermore, in this case when I try to open `192.168.1.1`, it takes a long time to load. I did many thing such as resetting the router, re-configuring it, changing its bandwidth from 40M to 20M and many other software solutions, but the problem wasn't solved. I also tried to update the `router` firmware, but in the official D-link website in my country there isn't any higher version to update it.

Now, how can I solve this annoying issue?

Is it a hardware problem of my router or something about ISP or my fiber cable?

I really appreciate any help you can provide. I hadn't this problem since I have bought this router.

Comment: Two things to try: (1) power off for at least 30 seconds, then power on again; (2) factory reset and power off for 30 seconds. If you do a factory reset, save your settings first (via Ethernet connection), so you can easily restore the current settings afterwards.

Comment: I did them before. @AFH

Comment: Then it sounds like a hardware problem: it's too expensive to replace ad hoc, so contact D-Link to investigate the cost of repair. I don't use routers at this level and I don't know why it's so expensive, but if all the cost is in the broadband interface then you can disable the WiFi and use a separate access point instead. This may be your cheapest solution.

Comment: Buy a new one. Maybe get a different brand next time.

Answer (score 0):

If *resetting* your router doesn't restore your wireless functionality, then it's very likely the router is defective.

You could try installing older firmware versions (if available). If any of them caused the wireless to start behaving properly, that would suggest the problem isn't hardware-related. However, if none of them change the unwanted behavior, that would add credibility to the conclusion the issue is with the hardware.